# MKMapView with custom pins return to red standard pins on reload

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have an MKMapView that I add pins to. They load correctly with their relevant graphics but if I zoom in and zoom back out they loose their graphic and turn into a standard red pin with the only customisation being the pin name (even my disclosure indicator disappear).

So far to try and fix it I've tried:
Tried png’s, checked on faster device, Changed everything from MKPinAnnotation to MKAnnotation, returning to a normal MKAnnotation instead of my custom CBAnnotation, Various sample codes for loading custom pins, Lowered quality of map overlay in case it was a loading issue but still an issue.

```
- (void)addPins {
    mapPinsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (MapPoint *mappoint in mapPointsArray) {
        CBAnnotation *annotation = [[CBAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mappoint.loclat, mappoint.loclong);
        annotation.title = mappoint.stopAreaName;
        annotation.mapPoint = mappoint;
        [mapPinsArray addObject:annotation];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(CBAnnotation *)annotation {

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        //do nothing
        return nil;
    } else {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"trailPoint"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        ButtonWithData *accessoryViewButton = [[ButtonWithData alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        [accessoryViewButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right_arrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        accessoryViewButton.buttonData = annotation.mapPoint;
        [accessoryViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(disclosureButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = accessoryViewButton;

        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:annotation.mapPoint.stopAnimalName]) {
            annotationView.image = [annotation.mapPoint lockedPinImage];
        } else {
            annotationView.image = [annotation.mapPoint unlockedPinImage];
        }

        return annotationView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem. I subclassed MKMapView to GenericMapView so that my code was cleaner (removing showsUserLocation, zoom/scroll/rotateEnabled, showsCompass etc. from the actual View Controller) but this meant the delegate wasn't setting correctly and viewForAnnotation wasn't being called on the pins reload.